# GetFullPath no output ?! VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, path

Good evening to all of you!
I have a problem that I can't solve with the method GetFullPath in vb.net.

**What I want to do :**

I would like to get the full path of a text file (test.txt) which is located in the same folder as the app.exe, the one I am working on. I need the full path to use an other method. To know more about the reason it doesn't work, I put the GetFullPath output in a MsgBox.

**What is happening :**

The MsgBox just shows a blank. This is really strange because, even if the test.txt doesn't exist, the output should exist (as if the file exists). 
WARNING : IN MY CASE THE FILE EXISTS

> Documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.100).aspx Cf. "Remarks"

**What I think about that :**

Is it possible that the app.exe doesn't see test.txt which is in the same folder ? I don't think so, it would give an outpout.
Maybe it is a problem of permission ? I really don't know why the MsgBox is empty.

*My peace of code :*

`Dim file1 As String = "test.txt"
 MsgBox(GetFullPath(file1))`

Thankyou to everyone who will try to help me.
Have a nice day ! :)
Please excuse my poor english.
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Are you by any chance executing this piece of code in the `Load` event of your form and are you on a 64 bits version of Windows?

Comment: I am executing it on a button click, and yes I use a 64bits Windows 7. Also the ReadAllText() method show nothing.

Comment: `System.IO.GetFullPath()` returns the absolute path for the specified path string.  It does **not** go find the file for you - it just works off the string passed.  If there is no drive or directory in the string, there cant be one in the return

Comment: yes, but the file is in the main folder, so the relative path is the name of the file, isn't it ?

Comment: It depends what is the current directory. Just passing in the filename will not work if the current directory isnt where the file is... it works off the current directory.

Comment: The test.txt file is in the folder of the app.exe. I can post a screenshot if you can't believe me ;)

Comment: Im not saying that. Find out what the current directory is first. How do you know its returning the directory that file sits in?

Comment: I dont know what "main folder" means, or even if you are calling `Path.GetFullPath()` vs a local method.  passing just a filename like that, it should append the current directory.  That doesnt mean that file exists there.  If you get no Msgbox at all, set a breakpoint and see if it gets there at all

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that... But my code is moving some files from directories to others, and renaming some, so I will be really surprised if it worked from all this time with a wrong current folder ! How can I be sure about that ? I'm a newbie with this language. When I said "main directory" I meant the directory where the app.exe sits in.

Comment: I just created a new solution and used a `MsgBox` to get the `GetFullPath` method and it worked just fine. The path that was returned is the path that the current exe is coming from. The file didn't exist either, but it just appended the file name to the end of that returned path. So it doesn't matter if it exists or not. If the `MsgBox` isn't showing post relevant code so we can help as to why. Also it does matter if you have permission as well to access that file.

Comment: I did it a lot of time, in other solutions, and it worked every time, but this time it can't...

Comment: Not sure, please post relevant code so we can help. It's hard to tell with nothing to go on. Also In my test I was able to use `If System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("Test.txt")) Then MsgBox("Exists!")` if the file was there. This tells me that `GetFullPath` is indeed working just fine on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears something in your code is changing the working directory (or in the case of Windows XP, it is not being set properly). The GetFullPath function I have provided below will return the path I believe you are expecting regardless of the working directory.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show(GetFullPath("file.txt"))
End Sub

Private Function GetFullPath(fileName As String) As String
    Return IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aeonhack ! I don't really understand why it didn't work but your solution solved my problem :) Have a nice day !

Comment: By the way, do you know why ReadAllText(GetFullPath("test.txt")) return nothing ? Is it possible that I don't have the permission to read it ? Really strange things are happening this week...

Comment: Could the problem be about FileIOPermissionAcess.Read ? I don't understand how to use it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this ,

```
Label1.Text = Application.StartupPath
```

You do all with this code ^^